# Blazor On click not working when routed through a certificate proxy

Tags: azure, blazor, cloudflare

I seem to have found a very strange issue.   After I published the Blazor Server App to Azure and got my domain connected with certs through Cloudflare, my buttons don't work.  You can see the pages below where 1 is direct from Azure and the other is the resolved domain name.  On this page there are 2 buttons that should expand menus.  Inside the main site (which is not exposed here) there are normal buttons as well as more menus that do not work.  Links work just fine.  It seems to only affect on click items.

The menus and buttons are Radzen controls if that clues anyone in.

Before I got the certificates working and getting the unsafe site warning the buttons were working on the resolved domain name as well.

https://easyonlineresume.azurewebsites.net/Resume/DemoDan
https://easyonlineresume.com/Resume/DemoDan

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to may own question.  Posting it here in case anyone else runs into it.  The issue ended up being in the Cloudflare optimization settings.  Navigate to Speed/Optimize.  Then clear the HTML check box.